# Net Core 2.1 Ajax Post to Controller

Tags: ajax, .net-core, asp.net-ajax

I have been pulling my hair over this one for some time now and just don't see what I'm doing wrong.

I have a series of fields in a SWAL dialog I want to post to my controller but for the life of me it just won't, doesn't even call the Post method. Error received is just the 400 error code.

```
var issue = JSON.stringify(this.swalForm);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../api/Issues",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("RequestVerificationToken",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            dataType: "json",
            data: issue,
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
            },
            success: function (msg) {
                console.log(msg.result);
            }
        });
```

That's my AJAX call

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostIssue([FromBody] Issue issue)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        _context.Issue.Add(issue);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetIssue", new { id = issue.Id }, issue);
    }
```

This is the Post Method in my controller

```
public partial class Issue
{
    public Issue()
    {
        Document = new HashSet<Document>();
        IssueMember = new HashSet<IssueMember>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public int? PriorityId { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int CreatedById { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public int? ModifiedById { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public User ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public Priority Priority { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Document> Document { get; set; }
    public ICollection<IssueMember> IssueMember { get; set; }
}
```

What the Model looks like

```
{"Title":"Ajax Issue","Description":"Made with ajax","DueDate":"2018-08-21","CategoryId":"3","StatusId":"2","PriorityId":"3","ProjectId":"1","Location":"Home","TeamId":"1","CreatedDate":"2018-08-21","CreatedById":"1","ModifiedDate":"2018-08-21","ModifiedById":"1","Active":"Active"}
```

And finally what the payload looks like on Post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out!! SMH...

Active is a bool variable in my controller but when checked it's passing a string "Active" to it. JSON doesn't match the model and therefore no call to the api method.

Check your payload and make sure it matches your models people!

Comment: Please set this question as answered so that we'll all know you have your problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript code seems ok. 1st try to debug web api using fiddler or postman then you will get exactly error message from PostIssue() method instead of 500.